Renaming across devices when destination already exists: is EXDEV guaranteed?
I am calling rename(2) with "old" and "new" paths on different devices. Am I guaranteed that the error code will be EXDEV, or can other error conditions take precedence?
Specifically:

If new_path is a non-empty directory, can I get ENOTEMPTY?
If using RENAME_NOREPLACE on Linux, can I get EEXIST?


POSIX allows implementations to support links between file systems, so it doesn’t make such guarantees.
On Linux, the only error that can be returned earlier than EXDEV by the rename syscalls is EINVAL. The calls are implemented in do_renameat2, which:

checks the flags for consistency, returning EINVAL if they aren’t,
checks for attempts to turn a directory into a subdirectory of itself, returning EINVAL in that case,
checks that the source and destination use the same mount, returning EXDEV if they don’t.

The second check doesn’t catch moves into a sub-mount, so they also return EXDEV — that is, cross-device renames with valid flags always return EXDEV, even if the expected result might be EINVAL. This isn’t explicitly documented, but any change in behaviour would be visible in user-space and would therefore qualify as a regression.
